# How select row from where condition passing MemberID ? Column contains List of memberID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column called MemberID which contains list of memberid like 
( 1|2|3|12|23|12 ) all Id separated by | I want can i pass one ID so get all row which contain provided ID.

[image]

Comment: Use a string splitter from [this site](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) to parse that pipe delimited string into a table... then use where MemberID in (select blah from function) or just inner join to it...

Comment: A very bad structure to store data separated by | `Pipe Symbol`, but you can go ahead with `LIKE` operator

Comment: Just normalise your schema

Comment: Also if you are using SQL 2016 you can use the built-in function [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

Comment: You are missing a table in your design to hold the members from a parliament

Comment: The reason you are struggling here is because you have violated 1NF by stuffing multiple values into a single tuple. Split that into a new table so you have relational data that is normalized and this issue will fix itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

> Supported Starting from SQL 2016

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
EID INT,
Sampl VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,'1|2|3|4')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2,'1|2|3|5')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (3,'1|2|3|4')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (4,'1|2|3|6')
GO

SELECT * FROM #Test 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT ( Sampl , '|' )
WHERE Value IN ('4')

RowID       EID         Sampl                                              value
----------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1           1           1|2|3|4                                            4
3           3           1|2|3|4                                            4
```

> For lower versions of SQL you may need to create a function to do the process

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString(@String NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter CHAR(1))    
RETURNS @Results TABLE (Result NVARCHAR(MAX))    
AS    
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @Index INT    
 DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(MAX)    

 SELECT @Index = 1    
 IF @String IS NULL RETURN  

 WHILE @Index != 0    
 BEGIN      
  SELECT @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)    
  IF @Index != 0    
   SELECT @Data = LEFT(@String, @Index - 1)    
  ELSE    
   SELECT @Data = @String    
  INSERT INTO @Results(Result) VALUES (@Data)    
  SELECT @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @Index)    
  IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK    
 END    
 RETURN  
END  


SELECT * FROM #Test 
CROSS APPLY Gemini.dbo.SplitString ( Sampl , '|' )
WHERE Result IN ('4')
```

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested it but this should work:

```
declare @Id varchar(10)='1'
select * from content_membeparticipation where charindex('|' + @Id + '|','|' + memberId + '|'  )>0
```

but I agree with the comments, if at all possible, the best option is normalise the tables